# Why CSS files are not preferred to be added in Angular 4 index page

Tags: angular

I have started working on Angular 4 recently, and what I can't understand is why CSS and JS files are included in `.angular-cli.json` and not in the `index.html` page itself?

I am unable to find any relevant link for this query on Google. Some people have suggested that it's not a good practice to use in HTML file directly, but why?

Comment: because the angular cli bundles and packages for you if you include them in the cli file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand what kind of CSS and JS files are included in `.angular-cli.json` file.

**Angular 4** is a framework which is based on component system. Each components is composed of 4 parts:

`page.component.ts` - Most imporant file in your page.component. Here you write functionality and link other components like html, css or test.

`page.component.html` - Here you write structure of your page in HTML

`page.component.css` - Here you can define style of your application using CSS.

`page.component.spec` - In this file you write tests for your application. By default with use of Jasmine framework.

Beside that there is also a global css file named `styles.css` which applies some rules to all components.

There are also CSS and JS files included in `.angular-cli.json` but these are mostly files connected with npm modules. You want to include then in angular-cli and give them a static path. If you have installed e.g Bootstrap4 through npm you have to link it's source code with angular-cli to make it work properly.

`index.html` is not that important in the whole application of Angular4. However you CAN interact with it in some way, style some of it's elements, add a loading screen etc.